# How to get all not answered orders

Tags: sql, sqlite

there is following db scheme:

```
Products:

ID|ProductType
--|-----------
1 |Car
2 |PC

Orders

ID|CustomerID|PruductID
--|--------------------
1 |     2    |  1
2 |    12    |  2
3 |    12    |  1

Bill
ID|OrderID|Price
--|-------|-----
1 |    2  | 200
2 |    3  | 2000
```

How to query the database on Orders which dont have a bill yet and get the data:

```
CustomerID|PruductID|ProductType
----------|---------|-----------
     2    |    1    |    Car
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not in`, `not exists`, or a `left join`.  Here is the latter:

```
select o.CustomerId, o.ProductId, p.ProductType
from orders o join
     products p
     on o.productId = p.Id left join
     bills b
     on b.orderId = o.Id
where b.id is null;
```

Comment: btw. Thank you Gordon